# How to check exit code of n commands ago?

Tags: bash, exit-code

I often mistype and now find myself trying to check the return code of **two** commands ago.

Is there a way to dereference the result of one before `echo $?`?

Comment: If you want to keep the last X number of exit codes,  you can save them in an array. You could simply create an array and keep a current of `index % size` to continually overwrite the oldest stored return in your array. You can reset the index each time `index % size` is zero. Otherwise, there is no built-in way to get anything other than the exit code for the last command.

Comment: if you are on macOs and use iTerm2, via *shell integration* you can enable **marks** on the left side of the prompt indicating the command exit status (either blue or red mark). See https://iterm2.com/documentation-shell-integration.html

Comment: It's not terribly difficult to add the exit status of the preceding command to your prompt; no special terminal support is required, aside from providing a scrollback buffer to *find* the preceding prompts.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin You can do: `a=("$?" "${a: 0:9}")` to prepend an array, limiting size to 10 elements (discarding oldest element when full), and maintaining order 0-10 for newest-oldest.

Comment: @dan Yep, that will get you a 2-eleement array of the exit codes with last exit code as `a[0]` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to store the exit code in a variable then you can use it later,
check the below snippet:

```
# assume that the n command ago for simplicity is 'ls'
ls
# the idea to store the exit code in a variable then you can use it later
EXIT_CODE_OF_OUR_CMD=$?

...
...
...
echo 'now we are here...'
...
...
# you can use and access $EXIT_CODE_OF_OUR_CMD variable anywhere
...
echo 'The status of the last n command ago=' $EXIT_CODE_OF_OUR_CMD
if [ $EXIT_CODE_OF_OUR_CMD -ne "0" ]; then
    echo 'our command is failed!, error code =' $EXIT_CODE_OF_OUR_CMD
    exit 1
fi
```